# How to restrict a BenchmarkDotNet job to run only on specific platforms?

Tags: f#, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I am writing an F# port of a program I wrote in native code in the past. I used [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to measure its performance. I also placed a native EXE in the application's output directory.

I set my native program as the baseline benchmark and saw it was 5x faster than my F# program. Just as I expected!

However, the native program is posted on GitHub and distributed as a Win64 binary only. In case somebody using another OS tries to run it, it will crash.

So, **how to specify that this benchmark will only run on 64-bit Windows?**

Comment: put it in a README?

Comment: Also there are some configuration settings in BenchmarkDotNet, e.g. platform: x64, see http://benchmarkdotnet.org/Configs/Jobs.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BenchmarkDotNet, there is a concept of [Jobs](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/Configs/Jobs.htm). Jobs define how the benchmark should be executed.
So, you can express your "x64 only" condition as a job. Note that there are several different 64x jit-compilers depends on runtime (LegacyJIT-x64 and RyuJIT-x64 for the full .NET Framework, RyuJIT-x64 for .NET Core, and Mono JIT compiler). You can request not only a specific platform but also a specific JIT-compiler (it can significantly affect performance), e.g.:

```
[<RyuJitX64Job>]
member this.MyAwesomeBenchmark () = // ...
```

In this case, a user will be notified that it's impossible to compile the benchmark for required platform.

Unfortunately, there is no way to require a specific OS for now (there is only one option: current OS). So, in your case, it's probably better to check [`System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem?view=netframework-4.7#System_Environment_Is64BitOperatingSystem) and [`System.Environment.OSVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion?view=netframework-4.7#System_Environment_OSVersion) at the start and don't run benchmarks on invalid operation systems.